# Fenvi pcie driver problem

Tags: pcie

I was hoping to find a workaround for a pcie wireless adapter that I recently purchased.  It is a model FV8802 from a company named Fenvi.  Currently there is no driver available from the company.  I am using Ubuntu 19.10. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Rather than the brand of device, the chipset used is more useful. I'd suggest looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide (esp. the device recognition section which will provide great clues for searching online, or asking us for help)

Comment: What is the version of kernel in  your system? Run the command `uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

On the official site of Fenvi, they do not seem to have drivers for Ubuntu. However, when i checked the chipset used in the wireless card, it was `Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265`. Intel has provided drivers for linux. [Here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz)